# My speller (cs50/pset5/speller) has a memory leak issue

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, cs50

I'm trying to run check50, but it says I have a memory leak issue. I ran `help50 valgrind ./speller texts/cat.txt`
, and it says:

```
==1430== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value? Take a closer look at line 36 of dictionary.c.
```

And also (the more complete message):

```
==1430== 
==1430== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1430==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1430==   total heap usage: 143,097 allocs, 143,097 frees, 8,023,462 bytes allocated
==1430== 
==1430== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1430== 
==1430== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1430== ERROR SUMMARY: 492 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So I guess I have to edit my check function, but I don't know what else to do. Here is my program (I would really appreciate if you could help ;)):

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define HASHTABLE_SIZE 65536

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = HASHTABLE_SIZE;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
unsigned int totalWords = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    //Initialize lower case word
    char lcword[LENGTH + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
        lcword[i] = tolower(word[i]);

    node *cursor = table[hash(lcword)];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    //https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/1x6vc8/pset6_trie_vs_hashtable/cf9nlkn/
    unsigned int hash_value = 0;

    for (int i=0, n=strlen(word); i<n; i++)
        hash_value = (hash_value << 2) ^ word[i];

    return hash_value % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    FILE *dicfile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char *word = malloc(LENGTH + 1);

    //Check if word is null
    if (word == NULL)
        return false;

    //Check if the fopen function opened a not NULL file
    if (dicfile == NULL)
       return false;

    //Iterate over dictionary until fscanf return EOF (meaning it's the end of the file)
    while (fscanf(dicfile, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        //Create a node to store the current word
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (new_node == NULL)
            return false;

        //Copy the new_node's word into the current word
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);

        //Get the index (hash the current word and store it in n)
        int n = hash(new_node->word);

        //Insert the new_node into the linked list
        new_node->next = table[n];
        table[n] = new_node;

        //Add to the total number of words in the text file
        totalWords++;
    }

    fclose(dicfile);
    free(word);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return totalWords;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        node* cursor = table[i];
        node* tmp;

        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        free(cursor);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And line 36 is this one:
`lcword[i] = tolower(word[i]);`

Thank you! Would love if you could solve this issue!

Comment: It's not a memory leak. Read the messages carefully. `no leaks are possible` means no mem leak. `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value` means a variable has not been set/intiialised at the point it is used. Provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and in particular show how `check` is called.

Comment: `tolower(word[i]);` You are iterating that array up to `LENGTH+1`. But I'm guessing the input is not guaranteed to be of that length. Need to stop at the end of the word.

Comment: Yes, I already tried replacing the `for` loop with a `while`, but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: Show what you tried. The type of loop is not important. How you use it is the important point. So show what you tried if you want help on that. That is, show how you are checking for the end of the word.

Comment: I used this loop (I'm trying this with a `for` loop:
`for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0' + 1; i++)
        lcword[i] = tolower(word[i]);`

Comment: `'\0' + 1` Not sure what you are intending there. That will compare `word[i]` with the ascii character that has value one more than the NUL. Remove the `+1`.

Comment: Hey! I removed this, but it still has another error

Comment: So, after fixing the error in the `for()` statement, there is another error.  Well, tell us the details of that other error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(CS50/pset5/speller) I have a memory leak issue, according to check50 and valgrind. I think I'm using a variable that doesn't have a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628478/cs50-pset5-speller-i-have-a-memory-leak-issue-according-to-check50-and-valgri)

Comment: This post is also from me, I just created this one so I could update everything...

Comment: I'll edit this question so you can see my problem

Comment: Hey! I discovered how to do it!!!!!!!! Instead of doing a `for` loop of the `LENGTH`, I used `strlen`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is in the type of the loop of the code. Instead of doing the for loop `LENGTH` times, you just have to do it the same number of times as the size of `word`. This is how it should look like:

```
//Initialize lower case word
    char lcword[strlen(word) + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word) + 1; i++)
        lcword[i] = tolower(word[i]);
```